# nginx - deploy angular(or static content) at multiple paths

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I want to deploy angular apps at multiple paths using nginx like this

```
location /path1 {
    root somethng;
    index index.html;
}
```

Sample index.html file

```
<script src="script.js" ></script>
```

With "/path1" in nginx, it will work only by changing html file to below code:

```
<script src="path1/script.js"></script>
```

If I set location to "/", then the relative paths to static files referenced in html files will work.

But if I set location to "/path1", it wont work till I change relative paths to include this "/path1/".

Is there any config in nginx so without making changes in angular code, the static files will be called with this "path1" ?

Please let me know for any questions ?

Comment: Provide details of which static files you're linking to.

Comment: Added ............

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how the client resolves path-relative URIs. If you enforce a trailing `/`, the path-relative URIs will be resolved correctly.

For example:

```
location /
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /path1/ {
    root somethng;
    index index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.